# Assiging a value to wtform field

Tags: python, python-2.7, wtforms, wt

I have a list as shown below

```
 self.glb_data_list = [{'disp_type': '2'}]
```

I want to assign this 'disp_type' value to wtform dropdown field 'disp_type'. Here is my wtforms field

```
    disp_type = fields.SelectField(u'Preset Mapping',
                                      choices=[(0, u'Custom'),
                                      (1, u'Loopback'),
                                      (2, u'All_East'),
                                      (3, u'All_Wast'),
                                      (4, u'16_East_16_West'),
                                      (5, u'8_East_8_West'),
                                      (6, u'STM1_East')],
                                    coerce=int, default=0)
```

Can somebody please guide me how I can assign

Comment: If you `coerce` to `int`, `glb_data_list` should be `[{'dist_type': 2}]` (an integer value)

Comment: Why glb_data_list is a list of dicts instead of just a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.glb_data_list = {'disp_type': 2}

disp_type = fields.SelectField(u'Preset Mapping',
                                      choices=[(0, u'Custom'),
                                      (1, u'Loopback'),
                                      (2, u'All_East'),
                                      (3, u'All_Wast'),
                                      (4, u'16_East_16_West'),
                                      (5, u'8_East_8_West'),
                                      (6, u'STM1_East')],
                                    coerce=int, default=0) 

disp_type.data = self.glb_data_list['dist_type']
```